# kaminari page_entires_info error with I18n.locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, kaminari

I use https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari for pagination on my rails projects.

On this page https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/issues/257 show the issue with this helper.

I have checked with adding to my gem file kaminari from master branch:

```
gem 'kaminari', :git => 'git://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari.git'
```

Also I have checked with last version `kaminari 0.14.1`, but it still does not translate to another language:

I can see on my view the error:

`Display Entries` with `translation missing: es.helpers.page_entries_info.more_pages.display_entries`

I have added to my `es.yml` the next code:

```
helpers:
    page_entries_info:
      one_page:
        display_entries:
          zero: "Ningún %{entry_name} encontrado"
          one: "Mostrando <b>1</b> %{entry_name}"
          other: "Mostrando <b>todos %{count}</b> %{entry_name}"
      more_pages:
        display_entries: "Mostrando %{entry_name} <b>%{first}&nbsp;-&nbsp;%{last}</b> de <b>%{total}</b> en total"
  views:
    pagination:
      first: "&laquo; Primero"
      last: "Último &raquo;"
      previous: "&lsaquo; Anterior"
      next: "Siguiente &rsaquo;"
      truncate: "..."
```

The views first, last, previous...etc is working fine but the `page_entries_info:` helper is  not working fine.

**if anyone has managed to solve this problem, would be nice if you share the solution. thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem with:

```
helpers:
  page_entries_info:
    one_page:
      display_entries:
        zero: "Ningún %{entry_name} encontrado"
        one: "Mostrando <b>1</b> %{entry_name}"
        other: "Mostrando <b>todos %{count}</b> %{entry_name}"
      more_pages:
        display_entries: "Mostrando %{entry_name} <b>%{first}&nbsp;-&nbsp;%{last}</b> de <b>%{total}</b> en total"
```

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue...
I've put this on my `pt-BR.yml`

```
pt-BR:
  views:
    pagination:
      first: "&laquo; Primeiro"
      last: "Ultimo &raquo;"
      previous: "&lsaquo; Anterior"
      next: "Proximo &rsaquo;"
      truncate: "..."
```

and this on my `application.rb`

```
config.i18n.available_locales = ['pt-BR']
```

Comment: Thank you, pagination is working fine, the problem is `helpers.page_entries_info` etc...

Answer (score 1):

add this to your locale:

```
helpers:
  page_entries_info:
    one_page:
      display_entries: "Mostrando todos os %{entry_name}"
    more_pages:
      display_entries: "Mostrando %{entry_name} <b>%{first}&nbsp;-&nbsp;%{last}</b> de <b>%{total}</b> no total"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can use this:

```
en:
  views:
    pagination:
      first: "&laquo; Primero" 
      last: "Último &raquo;"
      previous: "&lsaquo; Anterior"
      next: "Siguiente &rsaquo;"
      truncate: "..."
  helpers:
    page_entries_info:
      one_page:
        display_entries:
          zero: "No se encontraron datos, <strong>%{count}</strong> en total"
          one: "Mostrando solo <strong>%{count}</strong> %{entry_name}"
          other: "Mostrando un total de <strong>%{count}</strong> %{entry_name}"
      more_pages:
        display_entries: "Mostrando %{entry_name} del orden del <strong>%{first} al %{last}</strong> de un total de <strong>%{total}</strong>"
```

Not forget that set your *.yml to UTF-8 (for example in windows)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem, looking for another helper declaration inside my YML file, that was happening.
You have just to cut this kaminari's 'helpers' section, and paste in the section more below, in order to have one 'helpers' declaration into your file.

Looks like this:

```
helpers:
    page_entries_info:
      one_page:
        display_entries:
          zero: "Sem %{entry_name} encontrados"
          one: "Mostrando 1 %{entry_name}"
          other: "Mostrando todos %{count} %{entry_name}"
      more_pages:
        display_entries: "Mostrando %{entry_name} %{first} - %{last} de %{total} no total"
    select:
      prompt: Por favor selecione
    submit:
      create: Criar %{model}
      submit: Salvar %{model}
      update: Atualizar %{model}
```